# MACOS Log DeviceLog to file using filter and terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

i have a short question. 
How can I log Console > DeviceName into "myfile.txt" and filter incoming data by the process named "launchservices" using terminal.

A better view of the requested output can be seen in the next screenshot :

[The actual text i want to write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvF38.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found next cmd

sudo log stream | grep 'launchservicesd.*CHECKIN'

If you know something better please answer